# Figure out how a formula works

Tags: math, formula, deviation

I am using that site: http://167.71.255.125/#/dashboard/football/game/5359832 and i can't figure how it calculates the 'deviation' column whenever handicap home and away columns change. It probably uses standard deviation. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If it doesn't match any of the usual formulas for standard deviation, then you'll have to ask the owners of the web site how they do it.

Comment: Probably i do something wrong on calculations.

Comment: Still searching for that any help?

Comment: What did the site owners tell you?